# Export database from Oracle 11g Express Edition in .csv format

Tags: oracle

I don't know how to export database from Oracle 11g Express Edition. I want it in .csv format so that it will be easy for me to import it in MySQL.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export individual tables in SQL Developer from Oracle by right clicking on the table, selecting Export and then change the output format to .csv

Comment: can you be more specific, i am very new to oracle.   And thank you for answering.

Comment: Oracle has a program called "SQL Developer" you can download for free from their website. Installing, and then connecting this program to your database will allow to you do the steps as I described.